# com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Connection timed out (Read failed)

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, spring-boot, jdbc

I have a service which deletes and inserts records into tables from other tables based on the changes in data. When I run my service, It started transactions and seems working fine, after sometime it stuck at some point like it is waiting for some resources and after waiting for long hours it gives the connection time out exception. I checked with DBA and they cleared indexing and fragmentation on the tables and I also reduced no.of transactions at a time from 50k to 10K, no luck with any of these changes. I am trying to process around 3.8 millions of records on total.

Note: It was working fine with 2 cpu cores but used to take long hours to complete the run. So we increased 2 more cpu cores, after increasing the cores it worked fine for the 1st time, after that each time it is giving connection timeout exception.

Comment: Did you find any workaround to this? Facing a similar timeout erratically.

Answer (score 0):

Please check number of allowed active connection in sql server.
make sure you are closing your collection  properly after every call.